# display uploaded image in edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a edit form where I have to display the previously uploaded image by the  user. I searched on internet and tried with the solutions but it is not working. How can I show the uploaded image and it's name?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="required title_header">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="ImageFile" required name="ImageFile" accept="image/*">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="i_imagePrvw" class="thumbnail" style="display:none">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="i_targetImg" style="display:block; object-fit:fill;height:140px;width:120px;" />
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="#" onclick="clearPreview()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am retrieving the data in json format. In console log I am getting the values as::

```
"ImageTitle":"98570125698.jpg",
"ImagePath":"E:\\projects\\fis\\UI\\Files\\98570125698.jpg"
```

I am trying to set the image name and file via this code, but it is not working.

```
var image_ = data.firm_model[0].ImagePath;
$('#i_targetImg').html('<img src="' + image_ + '"/>');
$('#ImageFile').val(data.firm_model[0].ImageTitle);
```

Showing errors as

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/projects/fis/UI/Files/98570125698.jpg
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

Please do not mark as possible duplicate, first read the whole problem. I am trying to set the image and image name but I do not know, how to do. If you have the solution, please do a reply. Thank You!

Comment: The **ASP.NET MVC** is designed to prevent to access local resources for security reason, in way you are trying to do. Read the following article on the Microsoft site: [Working with Files in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Assuming that you are keeping your image (jpg) files in the folder `Files` inside your project. Then you can preview the uploaded image via using this code,

```
var image_ = "/Files/"+ data.firm_model[0].ImageTitle;
$('#i_targetImg').attr('src', image_);
```

You should be careful that the `Files` folder should be inside your root project directory. And regarding setting the name of the uploaded file in input attribute, please go through this link,
[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)